# How to change this value name in Firebase Databse?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change the name of "New List" to something else like "New List 2".
I can only change its value. Please tell me how to change the name of this child?

[This is my firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJaKX.png)

Comment: There is no "move"/"rename" operation in the Firebase Database API. You'll have to copy the node value to its new location and delete it from its old location.

Comment: can you please guide me how to do that?